# Terminal string в регулярном выражении библиотеки regex.h C

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c

Имеется регулярное выражение, компилируется функцией

```
regcomp(&regex, "1.ABC.DEF.[0-9]+", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Точки в данном случае будут означать любой символ. Их можно экранировать как "\\." или "[.]", но когда выражение большое, это не очень удобно. Есть ли возможность выделить терминальную строку, чтобы внутри этого выделения не искалось регулярное выражение? Пробовал "'1.ABC.DEF.'[0-9]+" и с прочими кавычками, но тщетно.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Никогда о таком не слышал, хотя задача в принципе актуальная. 

Только, конечно, не в плане лени при написании длинного, но константного выражения, а в случае, когда целое выражение динамически конструируется из разных источников и метасимволы являются таковыми не для всех них.

Очевидное решение -- написать функцию, экранирующую метасимволы и вызов ее для нужных частей. Но, конечно же, хотелось бы иметь аналогичную возможность, встроенную в `regcomp()`.

Если честно, даже не знаю, какие слова передать гуглу для релевантного поиска...

Comment: Я, к сожелению, не знаю С и тем более библиотеку regex.h, но если у нее возможности, как у pcre2.h, то синтаксис поддерживает \Q...\E заставляющий анализатор пропускать заврапленную часть регулярки